# Cannot find name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to include 'dom'.ts(2584)

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, deno

I want to convert a html string to a html element in deno with typescript. I found this function for it:

```
function createElementFromHTML(htmlString: string) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();

  return div.firstChild; 
}
```

When I run it with this command:

> deno run --allow-net .\scripts\API\fetchUtils.ts

It tells me this:

> Cannot find name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to include 'dom'.ts(2584)

After a bit of searching I found out that I need to add this to my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "DOM"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

I still get the same error, restarts etc. didn't help.

I don't know if it makes a difference but this is how my project is structured from the standpoint of where I start running the deno file from the console:

```
scripts
  -API
    -fetchUtils.ts
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Does including "DOM"  in "lib" (tsconfig.json) work? Isn't it "dom" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [vscode_deno #318](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/318)

`deno.config` might not be set as './tsconfig.json' (or path of it)

Just follow the issue mentioned if you are using vscode.
If not, [check your configuration](https://deno.land/manual/typescript/configuration#configuring-typescript-in-deno)